# Hide columns containing cells with certain values via Excel VBA button

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet with columns relating to dates Monday-Saturday from 2015-2020. When I print this sheet off I only want to see the "Monday" columns, not Tuesday-Saturday.  Row 14 has dates (dd/mm) and row 15 has day of the week (Ex. "M" for Monday, "T" for Tuesday, etc.).  I want to be able to toggle between hiding all non-Monday columns and seeing all columns. The VBA button code below gives me "Run-time error '13' - Type mismatch."  Is there a simple fix for this button, or is there a better way to accomplish this?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 11 To 222
        If Cells(14, i).Value = "T" Or "W" Or "R" Or "F" Or "S" Then
            Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
        Else
            Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is close, but that `IF ... OR ... OR` syntax is off. Your `OR` conditions are standalone and they have to contain an expression that evaluates to `True` or `False`.

So, instead, it should read:

```
If Cells(14, i).Value = "T" Or Cells(14, i).Value = "W" Or Cells(14, i).Value = "R" Or Cells(14, i).Value = "F" Or Cells(14, i).Value = "S" Then
```

Which is, admittedly, a lot more cumbersome, but it should do the trick.

Since the values you are looking for are a single Character, you could cheat a bit here and use `INSTR()`:

```
If Instr(1, "TWRFS", Cells(14,i).value) > 0 Then
```

So if your cell's value is in that string of weekday letters, then... do whatever

Comment: `.Hidden` is the correct one here. `.Visible` is not a property of a range.

Comment: Excellent. The cumbersome syntax is what I intended - Thank you!  Also same question as above - the > 0 in your If statement must just be a Yes/No or True/False response?  Sorry - I've used MatLab briefly, but other than that this is my first attempt at coding of any sort.

Comment: Yes, the `IF` needs a `TRUE` or `FALSE` to operate. `INSTR()` returns a number where the character can be found in the string. So if that is greater than 0, then the character is in the string, and the `IF` gets a `TRUE`. The `OR` statement before that would end up returning something like `TRUE OR FALSE OR FALSE OR FALSE OR FALSE` which is `TRUE` so `IF` is happy then too.

Answer (score 0):

Your narrative does not tell the same story as your code. The description puts the M, T, W, Th, F, Sa, Su in row 15 but the code looks in row 14.

In any event, I am determining the numerical [Weekday function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82yfs2zh%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) from what I hope are actual dates in row 14.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 11 To 222
        If Weekday(Cells(14, i).Value, vbMonday) > 1 Then
            Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden = _
                Not Columns(i).EntireColumn.Hidden
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

To toggle something on or off, simply reverse its boolean value.

Comment: Yes - it should have been row 15.  This solves my problem, but could you explain the  > 1 syntax in your If statement?

Comment: Did you click on the link I provided to the MSDN docs for the [WEEKDAY function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Weekday-Function-05D360D7-2C3F-4691-9448-C96EA0351940)? It is pretty straightforward. I'll be happy to clear up anything specific that you do not understand but I generally do not rewrite the documentation in comments.